# Calling specific version of python from PHP

Tags: php, python, exec, environment-variables

I'm setting up a big system relying on python 2.7 being run through php. The call is always something like:

```
exec('python test.py');
```

However no matter what I do PHP keeps using python 2.4 for executing my files. Because of the size of the system I can't change in the programming, but will have to make 'python' point directly to python2.7.

By searching around I have reached the conclusion that I should change the php env.

```
echo getenv("PYTHONPATH"); // NOTHING
echo getenv("PATH"); // /bin:/usr/bin
```

I can do so through `putenv` (for example: `putenv("PATH=/usr/bin/python2.7:".$_ENV["PATH"]`), but php keeps running python 2.4 no matter what I change it to.

Hope somebody out there got a simple solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another option, you can set path to interpreter in 1st line of script test.py

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
```

but you need make test.py  executable

```
chmod +x path_to_file/test.py
```

and run from php as

```
exec('path_to_file/test.py');
```

P.S. be attentive administrators sometimes disable exec function on servers for safety. 
disable_functions="popen,exec,system,passthru,proc_open,shell_exec" ....

Comment: Python is exec from around 100 different files so I will have to change the system which can't be done since the project is part of a big git project and is already running on other servers with the current python call. What I'm looking for is a way to change PHP enviromental path

Comment: i'm not sure, but i read about option python.append_path for php.ini   
http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php
or find and replace your exec(...) command like proposed

Comment: The python.append_path sounds like a good solution, but can i change that without changing the php.ini, and if yes -how?

Comment: if you using apache and mod_python installed you can set PythonPath in  htaccess [look here](http://www.modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/dir-other-pp.html) , or google such solution for nginx =))
 although personally I would not install extension just for this thing, find and replace 10-20 strings of you code easiest solution

Answer (score 3):

Could you not just do this instead:

```
exec('/usr/bin/python2.7/python test.py');
```

Comment: Python is exec from around 100 different files so I will have to change the system.

Comment: @Bornakke It should be pretty straightforward to build a shell script to search and replace your expressions, optionally asking for your approval before changing them.

Comment: Can't do. The project is part of a big git project and is already running on other servers with the current python call. What I'm looking for is a way to change PHP enviromental path.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use full path, try an alias:

```
alias python='/usr/bin/python2.7'
python --version
Python 2.7.2
```

Comment: Alias works in the terminal and when I run python here I get the right version. But Alias doesn't change the way PHP make use of python.

Comment: Did you try to set alias for user (nobody or www-data) who runs web server?

Comment: yep. But it is already the same user. But PHP wouldn't use the alias, since the env. path is defined inside php.ini.